# How to increase volume of node-chrome-debug using docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to increase the volume of the chrome node so that it does not crashes , one way to achieve is -

```
$ docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --shm-size 2g selenium/node-chrome-debug
```

But how do i write this in a docker compose file.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this =)

```
version: "2.0"
    services:
      app:
        image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
        ports:
          - "4444:4444"
        shm_size: "2g"
```